# How can I reopen a closed file handle in Perl?

Tags: perl, syntax, io, filehandle

Once a file handle is closed is it possible to reopen it without creating a new file handle?

ex (This doesn't work):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Open and write to a file
open my $fh, '>', 'file.txt' or die $!;
print $fh 'Hi!';
close $fh;

# Reopen the file and read its contents
open $fh, '<' or die $!;
my @contents = <$fh>;
close $fh;

print @contents;
```

I'm trying to avoid doing this:

```
open my $fh2, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
```

Comment: Can't you just not close `$fh`?

Comment: Reopening of closed handle is not possible. You have two choices: don't close handle too early or reopen whole file.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. In the above code, I would simply store `Hi!` in a variable; reading it from the file would be both unnecessary and expensive. I assume you want to open the file read/write and use `seek` as [sidyll suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32701741/176646), but it would help if you explained why you want to do this; we may be able to suggest a better way.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was possible to reopen a closed file handle.  It would just make for some nice syntactic sugar, but if it's not possible, opening it for read/write and not closing it until the end will get the job done.

Comment: [Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File) lets you treat the contents of a file as an array, which can be nice if you're doing lots of random-access reads and writes. Not sure if that's the kind of thing you're looking for.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by doing this? You cannot "reopen" a file descriptor, because it no longer exists. That's the point of 'closing' it.

Comment: I was really just trying to do something with a file at the beginning of a script and then do something else with it near the end and I didn't want to create an entirely new file handle.  My question is generic, there's no real specific usage case I had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot  "reopen" it. The best  solution is to avoid  closing, if you
need it later.  Remember that you can alway use  [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) if you need
to rewind to some portion of the file.

```
# open for read/write
open my $fh, '+<', 'file.txt' or die $!;

# do something to file, like writing

# go to the beginning
seek FILEHANDLE, 0, 0;

# do something else, like reading
```

Comment: You'll have to open it read/write first (the OP wants to do both): `open my $fh, '+<', 'file.txt' or die $!;`

Comment: Yes well noted @ThisSuitIsBlackNot. I added this to the answer to make it more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can reopen a closed handle. But, you can reuse the $fh variable as a filehandle since it's been closed. But, you're missing the name of the file when you open again.

```
open $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
```

Comment: I would delete this answer, because it does not answer the question.